# Get borderRadius of parent widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way at all we can get the parent widgets borderRadius property?
If it makes things any clearer, this is the context of asking the question:
I'm authoring the glass package on pub.dev/packages/glass. It allows you to convert any widget to a glass version by calling an extension .asGlass() method on it, which involved a ClipRRect widget. However, since I don't know if the widget on which asGlass is called has a borderRadius, sometimes the glass effect extends over the borders of the parent widget (i.e. the widget has rounded borders, while the glass effect has rectangular borders).
So is there any way I can get the borderRadius or any property at all from the calling widget without the user having to pass it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the value of a `borderRadius` is a cleaner approach and should be followed.

You can make an optional radius argument with default value of 0. A rectangle is rendered unless a `borderRadius` is specified.

```dart
asGlass(BorderRadiusGeometry borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero){...}
```

Now whenever your parent has a border radius just pass it in:

```
var _borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(10);
Card(
 ...,
 borderRadius: _borderRadius,
).asGlass(_borderRadius);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed the approach that I ended up following (see https://pub.dev/packages/glass). Thanks for answering.